# 'CSS i-amphtml- name prefix' disallowed error in amp carousel

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

My site's amp url gives me this error:

```
The text inside tag 'style amp-custom' contains 'CSS i-amphtml- name prefix', which is disallowed.

Line 27:2
<style amp-custom>
```

As I go through almost all the files of better-amp plugin (using this for wordpress amp), I found the `i-amphtml` located in this file:

```
class-better-amp-carousel-component.php
```

code snippet from the file:

```
/**
     * Register shortcode to display galleries as carousel on amp version
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function config() {
        return array(
            'shortcodes' => array(
                'gallery'           => array( $this, 'handle_gallery' ),
                'better-amp-slider' => array( $this, 'handle_slider' ),
            ),
            'scripts'    => array(
                'amp-carousel' => 'https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js'
            )
        );
    }
```

seems like `https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js` this file contains the disallowed prefix.

unfortunately I couldn't alter any of the code in this file as it says permission denied. I tried changing folder and file permission as well but couldn't.

Why would amp carousel throw this error and what's the proper way to fix this?

Comment: Does your CSS files has `.i-amphtml`? Kindly remove that.

Comment: As Jess mentioned and the error states it looks as if your custom css defines that css class. Check the contents of your custom styles within tags <style amp-custom>...</style>

Answer (score 3):

you could add a workaround via the attribute selector as a last resort meassure.

```
[class*="amphtml-carousel-slide-item"] {}
```

This targets all elements whose classlist contains the string `amphtml-carousel-slide-item`, so this would include something like `i-amphtml-carousel-slide-item` without causing a validation error.

Comment: So while this works around the validation it doesn't fix the root cause. Honestly through I see this more of a problem with amp. First and foremost I'm stuck using their super-limited set of widgets then second I can't even style them? Might as well go back to the internet of the early 90's!

Answer (score -3):

Remove all the .i-amphtml in the CSS of AMP